# react-konva find all elements inside a group to check for collisions

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I am using react-konva (typescript) and have a number of elements inside a group, now I want to check for any collisions when I drag 1 element around.

I have seen [this page](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Collision_Detection.html), but that uses javascript and not typescript.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
<Stage>
    <Layer>
        <Group>
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Image />
            <Text />
            <Text />
        </Group>
    </Layer>
</Stage>
```

I use a transformer to see the anchor points of an element I am dragging around. But I am not sure how to check for any collisions (like the example page).

Any help would be nice.

Comment: That page is the way to do it. Adapt it into TypeScript.